POS add field in pos.config issue
When I try to add my custom added field restrict_create_customer to pos.config and inherit _loader_params_pos_config to add field in pos.session in odoo 16 it raises this error

my python code:
class PosConfigInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'pos.config'
    restrict_create_customer = fields.Boolean(help="Show employee login screen")



class ConfigSettingsInherit(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'
    pos_module_restrict_create = fields.Boolean(related='pos_config_id.restrict_create_customer', readonly=False)



class PosSession(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'pos.session'

    def _loader_params_pos_config(self):
        result = super()._loader_params_pos_config()
        result['search_params']['fields'].append('restrict_create_customer')
        return result


I found the solution,it`s actually there is no need to load field of pos.config to POS Session it is loaded automatically and you can get it in pos session developed by odoo.
